# SVG Shape Tweening

Tags: svg, d3.js, svg-animate

I want to change one shape to another. I tried to use D3.js, there is one point which is out of map when the transition is happening. Here is the example:

```
function loop() {
path
    .attr("d", d0)
  .transition()
    .duration(5000)
    .attr("transform","scale(1.5)")
    .attr("d", d1)
  .transition()
    .delay(5000)
    .attr("d", d0)
    .each("end", loop);
```

}

Which you can see in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/41q6offb/)

You can see 2 different resulting shapes after transition, what I want is, the transition should start with one of those two shapes and it should end to another shape.

Any ideas?

Comment: In order to tween the two shapes smoothly, they need to have the exact same number of points.  Otherwise, the extra points from the second shape just get tacked on the end of the path from the first shape -- or cut off, if you are tweening in the other direction.

Comment: I was thinking same as u but as I can see here, I dont think there are same number of points.
http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3081153

Comment: Actually, that code specifically creates the path for a circle using exactly the same number of points as the original map shape -- look at the `circle()` function.

Comment: You might find [this recent post on CSS Tricks](http://css-tricks.com/svg-shape-morphing-works/) useful for explaining shape morphing.  That example uses SVG/SMIL animation instead of d3 transitions, but the concept is the same: you need to define how each point (including control points for curves) is going to move.

Comment: Yes, I figure out, the number of points has to be same. Thanks for your help.

Comment: If not using D3, how can I create an array of distances/points rather then an array of functions?